# looking for an http-in node to handle ssl inbound web services

Tags: node-red

does anyone know of a replacement node for http-in for ssl?  Thinking my only alternative would be to start nodejs as an https-server?

any suggestions would be great.

Thanks, Den

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a replacement node (and I don't believe there are any as it would need to instantiate it's own HTTPS server independent from Node-RED), you just configure Node-RED to listen for HTTPS connections.

How to configure Node-RED to listen on HTTPS is in the `settings.js` (found in the Node-RED user directory, which is normally ~/.node-red and is included in the first few lines of the Node-RED log)

```
// The `https` setting requires the `fs` module. Uncomment the following
// to make it available:
//var fs = require("fs");
...
// The following property can be used to enable HTTPS
// See http://nodejs.org/api/https.html#https_https_createserver_options_requestlistener
// for details on its contents.
// See the comment at the top of this file on how to load the `fs` module used by
// this setting.
//
//https: {
//    key: fs.readFileSync('privatekey.pem'),
//    cert: fs.readFileSync('certificate.pem')
//},
...
```

More details can be found in my blog post [here](https://www.hardill.me.uk/wordpress/2015/05/11/securing-node-red/)